# Errors using LibGdx with Google Play Services/BaseGameUtils (Gradle)

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I am using Eclipse, LibGdx 1.0.1, Latest Google Play Lib, and Latest BaseGameUtils from https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples

(Gradle Project)

My BaseGameUtils has a few errors

**GameHelper.java**

```
// Api options to use when adding each API, null for none
GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mGamesApiOptions = null; //error with this line
GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mPlusApiOptions = null; //error with this line
GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions mAppStateApiOptions = null; //error with this line

/**
 * Sets the options to pass when setting up the Games API. Call before
 * setup().
 */
public void setGamesApiOptions(GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions options) { //error with this line
    doApiOptionsPreCheck();
    mGamesApiOptions = options; //error with this line
}

/**
 * Sets the options to pass when setting up the AppState API. Call before
 * setup().
 */
public void setAppStateApiOptions(GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions options) { //error with this line
    doApiOptionsPreCheck();
    mAppStateApiOptions = options; //error with this line
}

/**
 * Sets the options to pass when setting up the Plus API. Call before
 * setup().
 */
public void setPlusApiOptions(GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions options) { //error with this line
    doApiOptionsPreCheck();
    mPlusApiOptions = options; //error with this line
}

/**
 * Creates a GoogleApiClient.Builder for use with @link{#setup}. Normally,
 * you do not have to do this; use this method only if you need to make
 * nonstandard setup (e.g. adding extra scopes for other APIs) on the
 * GoogleApiClient.Builder before calling @link{#setup}.
 */
public GoogleApiClient.Builder createApiClientBuilder() {
    if (mSetupDone) {
        String error = "GameHelper: you called GameHelper.createApiClientBuilder() after "
                + "calling setup. You can only get a client builder BEFORE performing setup.";
        logError(error);
        throw new IllegalStateException(error);
    }

    GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(
            mActivity, this, this);

    if (0 != (mRequestedClients & CLIENT_GAMES)) {
        builder.addApi(Games.API, mGamesApiOptions); //error with this line
        builder.addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES);
    }

    if (0 != (mRequestedClients & CLIENT_PLUS)) {
        builder.addApi(Plus.API, mPlusApiOptions); //error with this line
        builder.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN);
    }

    if (0 != (mRequestedClients & CLIENT_APPSTATE)) {
        builder.addApi(AppStateManager.API, mAppStateApiOptions); //error with this line
        builder.addScope(AppStateManager.SCOPE_APP_STATE);
    }

    mGoogleApiClientBuilder = builder;
    return builder;
}
```

So I added `//error with this line`  on the lines with you guessed it errors.

Like I mentioned before I believe that I have the latest libraries, and I am sure my projects are linked correctly. I also have the necessary lines of code in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been some API changes on Google Play Game Services 4.4 that have not yet been reflected on the Android Samples project (https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils) or documented by Google (as far as I know).

Have a look to the comments on G+ Android Developers entry:

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/8957tqzymuM

You can either use the community modified GameHelper, wait for Google to update the sample project or reverse to GPGS 4.3.

Comment: my rep isn't high enough lol.                                                 Where can i get 4.3?

Answer (score 1):

I used source from https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils but my application crashed with following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Null options are not permitted for this Api at
.. com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.createApiClientBuilder(GameHelper.java:286    ) at 
com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.setup(GameHelper.java:319) at
com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:105).
```

I have changed BaseGameActivity onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    if (mHelper == null) {
        getGameHelper();
    }
    mHelper.setPlusApiOptions(new Plus.PlusOptions.Builder().build());
    mHelper.setup(this);
}
```

and error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code available here instead: https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelVinas/ef09a35bcc805ba6deb3

Just cut everything from the imports of GameHelper.java to the end of it and then paste the contents of that gist as a replacement.

it works